# How can I set binds variable into alias name in Snowflake Stored Procedure?

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to change column name using binds
in a javascript stored procedure.
But it does not work.

I tried the following script.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE1 (COL_NAME VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('XXXXX');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1("ALIAS_NAME" VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var sql_command = `
        CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TABLE2 AS
        SELECT COL_NAME AS :1
        FROM TABLE t1;
    `
    var result = snowflake.execute(
        {
         sqlText: sql_command,
         binds: [ALIAS_NAME]
        }
    );
    return "finished";
$$
;

call PROC1('ALIAS_NAME')
```

Error message is

```
Execution error in store procedure PROC1: SQL compilation error: sytax error line 3 at postion 27 unexpected ':'. At Snowflake.execute, line 7 position 27
```

It seems that "binds" expression does not work well.
Do you have any idea to work it well?

Comment: I can reproduce it as well. Please open a case with Snowflake support to report it, as I am not sure if it was ever intended to work for this particular scenario.

Comment: Changing the alias using bind may not be supported, Changing the alias name dynamically is a special ask. Snowflake SP bind option https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009E2qFHSAZ/how-do-i-bind-a-date-within-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @Sergiu It would be nice to use identifier not only for object names but also in every place identifier is required(like column names/aliases/constraint_names etc).  [Similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536639/dynamic-column-name-in-snowflake)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I agree with you, therefore suggested to have a case opened with Snowflake support. To me it looks like a bug as we don't specifically document we don't support this scenario.